# passing NSString to UILabel using delegate method

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I made delegate to transfer back from one view controller to another a string.

The onSave method:

```
-(void)onSave:(NSString*)nameValue{
    NSLog(@"onSave in father controller");
    self.NameValue.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Name= %@",nameValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",nameValue);
    NSLog(@"%@",self.NameValue.text);
}
```

The first NSLOG print nameValue (NSString) for example print: 123 and the second NSLOG print NameValue (UILabel) but print NULL!!

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise the label before doing this, otherwise you'll be adding an object (your string) to something that is `nil`.

Comment: Using NSLOG i cant "see" the nameValue that is passed correctly to onSave method. After self.NameValue.text = ......" the NameValue is null   @Daniel Morandini